# ¿como hacer un insert con una condición?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola ¿es posible hacer un insert con un where? les platico la problemática, tengo tres tablas en mi base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la tabla **ScheduleDetails** se junta la información de las otras dos tablas, quiero poder insertar un registro en la tabla ScheduleDetails cuando exista un registro que tenga el mismo ScheduleID, algo más o menos como lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO ScheduleDetails VALUES (DocType, Description, Value) WHERE Schedules.ScheduleID = 100;
```

Sé que esa instrucción no es correcta, pero es algo así lo que busco, de antemano gracias. DTB
Estoy usando Sql server

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Tengo un datagridview en el cual se modifica la información, para esto tengo las consultas de update, con la información proveniente de la base de datos, pero quiero ahí mismo poder insertar y eliminar los registros, por ejemplo si edito los que vienen por defaul (me refiero a los que se ingresaron en la creación del registro) pues simplemente se hace el update, pero si ingreso un nuevo registro debe hacer el insert cuando el  Schedules.ScheduleID coincida con el valor que le pasare.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De donde salen los datos que insertarás en ScheduleDetails?

Comment: ¿Te has planteado resolver esto con un **disparador** (TRIGGER)? Es una herramienta que programas una sola vez, y cuando ocurra un cambio en una tabla, puedes modificar otra(s) tabla(s) automáticamente. ¿O quizá sea algo que deberías resolver con **restricciones de integridad referencial**? No parece una buena idea querer re-inventar la rueda, cuando existen ya herramientas para automatizar este tipo de tareas.

Comment: Hola @LuisCazares actualicé la pregunta

Comment: lo que estas planteando, simplemente no tiene sentido.. un insert, inserta datos.. por lo cual, para que querria el where (que especifica que filas se van a devolver?) no termino de entender tu condicion, pero parece una regla de negocios y no algo que tenga que ver con la db... Y no confundas lo que tenes en pantalla, con lo que tenes en la db...